# Dishwasher and outlet doesn't work

Tags: electrical, dishwasher

During Thanksgiving I believe my wife must have overloaded an electrical outlet that must be connected to our dishwasher somehow but now neither work and I've tried all of the breakers in my electric box to see if any tripped, none tripped.?????

Comment: Look for a tripped GFCI outlet.  Also most residential circuit breakers don't move to the off position when they trip, usually you can tell by touching each breaker handle -- if you find a loose feeling handle move it all the way to the Off position then snap it back on.

Comment: Is there a switch that controls the outlet somewhere?

Comment: Is the dishwasher on a dedicated circuit? If so, it could be plugged into a receptacle behind it and someone has put in a GFCI receptacle. This was not be according to the code because it would not be readily accessible, but is one explanation for your condition. You will have to pull the dishwasher out to how it is powered. At that time you could check to see if it is getting power..